# ("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-ec2

I tried deploying my project to an AWS EC2 server but when I tried to run `php artisan migrate` I am getting the following error.

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
>
> PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=myDb", "root", "", [])

The following is my .env file:

```
PP_NAME="MyProject"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:UTBgGqkc11OYbnGGJVe32xFluhFeNw288oH0UcmMYqU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` and then `php artisan migrate`

Comment: @JGEscarilla still the same, i edited the error message, not sure if it helps

Comment: does your AWS EC2 server has a password? I think it has.

Comment: no, but my mysql's root user has one, i tried using that password in DB_PASSWORD. I also tried using secret.

Comment: you must put that password. that is why it prompts `using password: NO` because it is looking for the password.

Comment: double check if root user granted to access db using 127.0.0.1 try with localhost, or create new user that can access the db locally and using 127.0.0.1

Comment: You can connect database by phpmadmin

Comment: @JGEscarilla i tried it with the password, nothing happens.

Comment: Hi guys, I finally found out what was wrong. I posted the answer below. Thank you for taking time to help me out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I got it fixed. All I did was run `php artisan config:clear`. The problem was I had a previous migration already done with wrong credentials and everything. So after running `php artisan config:clear` I went ahead and ran `php artisan migrate` and everything was fine.

Thanks all for your time.